# How to get particular array of user (mongodb, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> my backend

Can any one please tell me i have number of users in my mongodb. For example I have 3 users in my database, on that 2 users have reviews and the rest of the one user have no reviews. who have reviews i need to get only that users to frontend. My mongodb structure is:

_id:ObjectId("123")
username:"xx"
email:"xx"
reviews:Array
0:Object

While i am using this below code i am getting all users to frontend.but i need only who have reviews, only that user i need to get to frontend.

```
//Getting reviews in Users to homepage
  userRouter.post('/getreviews', (req, res) => {
    Collections.user.find({}, {"reviews":1,"username":1},  function (err, result) {
    if (result) {
      //    console.log(result);
  res.status(200).json({users:result.map((user) => user.reviews)});
    } else {
   res.status(500).send("User Not Found with Details: " + JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    })
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add condition in first {} to check whether reviews exists or not
**{"reviews": {$exists: true}}**

//Getting reviews in Users to homepage

```
 userRouter.post('/getreviews', (req, res) => {
    Collections.user.find({"reviews": {$exists: true}}, {"reviews":1,"username":1},  function (err, result) {
    if (result) {
      //    console.log(result);
  res.status(200).json({users:result.map((user) => user.reviews)});
    } else {
   res.status(500).send("User Not Found with Details: " + JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    })
    });
```

Comment: Reviews are getting in console. but if it is an empty array, i dont need to get that user. but now i am getting all reviews either it is empty or with data, showing in console.

Comment: In my database now there are three users. On that only one user have review rest of two users have no reviews. but console is showing three users. I need only Array(1) users.        my console..----->   users: (3) [Array(1), Array(0), Array(0)]

Comment: you can try this 
connection.collection('user', function(error, collection) {
   if(error) {
    //console.log(error);
    return;
   }
   else {
    collection.find({"reviews": {$exists: true}}, {"reviews":1,"username":1}).toArray(function(error,results) {
     debug(results);
       
    });
   }
  });

Comment: userRouter.post('/getreviews', (req, res) => {
    Collections('user', function(error, collection)
    { if(error) { //console.log(error); return; 
    } else { collection.find({"reviews": {$exists: true}},
    {"reviews":1,"username":1}).toArray(function(error,results) 
    { debug(results); }); } });
});  ....I wrote like this.but it shows collection is not a function

Comment: connection.collection() 
connection object is your mongoDb coinnection object
dont use collection directly

Comment: It shows connection is not defined. I also put user in place of connection it shows user is not defined